# Chart a divergence between two time fields in the same elasticsearch index with timelion

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, timelion

So I have an elastic search index with lots of data and I have found an issue with some of the data that I would like to visualise. Some items in the index matched under the ***itm.description*** field as say **FOO** have two timestamp entries called ***itm.timestamp*** and ***itm.jmsTimestamp***.

These two fields have started to diverge quite considerably when they were very close a few days ago. Some ActiveMQ processing is going on between the two so that seems like the likely cause but I would like to visualise when this started and what the drift is over the last few days in Kibana using timelion.

```
.es(index=myindex*,q='itm.description:FOO',timefield='@itm.timestamp'),.es(index=myindex*,q='itm.description:FOO',timefield='@itm.jmsTimestamp')
```

So clearly this query is not particularity helpful as it produces two flat lines. What do I need to produce a graph that displays the difference in the drift between the two timestamps using timelion? Is it possible to display the two timestamps overlayed or would graphing the drift be more useful?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the `subtract`-expression?

Something like this:

```
.es(index=myindex*, q='itm.description:FOO', timefield='@itm.timestamp', metric=max:'@itm.timestamp').subtract(.es(index=myindex*, q='itm.description:FOO', timefield='@itm.timestamp', metric=max'@itm.jmsTimestamp'))
```

You cannot use the direct values of a field, Timelion requires an aggregation, as it renders 1 value per bucket. In my example, I used the `max`-aggregation.

Another solution would be to introduce a new field that you populate at indexing time with the delta of the two timestamp fields. Again you would need to use an aggregation for value to be displayed on the y-axis.

Comment: I really do want the difference between the direct values in the two fields for each data point matching the query so that I can see the exact difference over a specified period, is timelion not the place to do this?

Comment: With the solution approaches, I outlined above, the actual delta's get calculated (on a point-per-point base). Kibana itself is not really about rendering individual documents, one exception to that is the Discover interface, another the new Maps-visualization. Timelion simply can't do that, it is specialized to visualize time series data, creating buckets representing a time interval, not individual documents.

Comment: Thank you @DanielSchneiter, so as the answer gives a blank chart are you saying that getting a difference between two time fields is not possible?